# reportlab pdf vs javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, reportlab

i' d like to add some javascript code to my pdf (which is generated by reportlab). For me it' s ok to add it during the pdf generation, but i can' t find any working way to achieve this.

Could anyone suggest me a howto or a snippet how to do this?

I' ve a textfield:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
c = canvas.Canvas('form2.pdf')
c.acroForm.textfield(value='1', name='tfield', forceBorder=True)
```

and i' d like to change its value with javascript.

How could i achieve it?

---

i tried using

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfdoc
pdfdoc.pdfdoc.PDFCatalog.OpenAction = '<</S/JavaScript/JS(document.getElementById("tfield").value = "bbb");)>>'
```

, but when i open the pdf, the value is still intact (however the js code got into the pdf).

Comment: So the javascript part would be most probably very trivial, but how can i add my js code to the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

The script that you've added isn't Acrobat JavaScript. Acrobat JavaScript has a completely different object model. The Core is the same but you can't use an HTML DOM on a PDF.

The JS portion of your code would be...

```
this.getField("tfield").value = "bbb"
```

In the context of a document open action "this" **is** the document. The documentation for the Acrobat extensions to JavaScript is located here...

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FJavaScript_API.htm